# Поиск строки в CSV и её удаление как метод класса

Tags: python-3.x, csv

Необходимо найти строку в CSV файле которая будет содержать заданные пользователем элементы и удалить эту строку целиком из файла.
Как этого достичь?

Comment: Проще всего использовать Pandas наверное

Comment: не знаком с ним совершенно.

Comment: если речь о строках в файле, то алгоритм банален: копируете **нужные** строки в новый файл, затем новый файл переименовываете. profit.

Comment: не совсем уверен что правильно понял как именно это можно реализовать